# hide folder name in tree list

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

how do i hide specific name folder within the treelist ? i have tree list like this

[image]

and i want to hide folder name `New folder` and `pdf`. i make this from [Load Data Dir](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/5562/Controls-and-Libraries/Tree-List/Examples/Data-Binding/How-to-Load-Data-Dynamically-via-Events). i have tweak a bit in the code like this by putting `if`

```
Dim rootfolder As String = "C:\\FFOutput"

Private Sub TreeList1_VirtualTreeGetCellValue(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraTreeList.VirtualTreeGetCellValueInfo) Handles TreeList1.VirtualTreeGetCellValue
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(CStr(e.Node))
    If di.Name <> "New folder" Then
        If e.Column Is TreeListColumn1 Then
            e.CellData = di.Name
        End If
        If e.Column Is TreeListColumn2 Then
            e.CellData = e.Node.ToString

        End If
        If e.Column Is TreeListColumn3 Then
            If IsFile(di) Then
                e.CellData = New FileInfo(CStr(e.Node)).Extension
            Else
                e.CellData = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TreeList1_VirtualTreeGetChildNodes(ByVal sender As Object,
ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraTreeList.VirtualTreeGetChildNodesInfo) _
Handles TreeList1.VirtualTreeGetChildNodes
    If loadDrives = False Then            
        Dim root As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(rootfolder)
        e.Children = root
        loadDrives = True
    Else
        Try
            Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(CStr(e.Node))
            If di.Name <> "New folder" Then
                Dim path As String = CStr(e.Node)
                If Directory.Exists(path) Then
                    Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(path)
                    Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(path)
                    Dim arr(dirs.Length + files.Length) As String
                    dirs.CopyTo(arr, 0)
                    files.CopyTo(arr, dirs.Length)
                    e.Children = arr                        
                Else
                    e.Children = New Object() {}
                End If
            End If
        Catch

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

and it become like this

[image]

Comment: You can't really add a node and then hide it. Either it's there or it's not. You need to determine the criteria by which you want to exclude nodes and then include that logic in the code that builds the tree. If you encounter data that meets the criteria for exclusion then don't create a node for it.

Comment: then how to i exclude nodes determined by the folder name ?

Comment: It's called an `If` statement.  You determine what criteria you want to use and `If` the current data satisfies the criteria to be included then you create a new node, `Else` you don't.

Comment: but as you can see. iam already puttin `if` statement. however the ouput interface is not what i desired :)

Comment: Then step through your code in the debugger to determine exactly where what actually happens is different to what you expect.